# Annotate propagation and isolation in Transaction using spring properly

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I've written a task scheduler job which generates bills for the eligible patients for every 30 min. Here I'm confused whether the propagation and isolation levels which I've kept are correct as per standard. Should I use always REQUIRES_NEW as part of propagation?

Any suggestions on the below part.

```
private void startBilling() throws Exception {
    List<Integer> patientIds = null;
    try {
        patientIds = getPatientsForBilling();
        if(null != patientIds) {
            for(Integer patient : patientIds) {
                updatePatientDetails(patient, "STARTED", jdbcTemplate);
                makeBillForPatient(patient, jdbcTemplate);
                updatePatientDetails(patient, "COMPLETED", jdbcTemplate);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         //LOG HERE
         updatePatientDetails(patient, "TERMINATED", jdbcTemplate);
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class,isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
private void makeBillForPatient(Integer patient, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2) {
    // A bill for the patient will be generated and printed
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class,isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
private void updatePatientDetails(Integer patient,
        String status, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    // Update the patient billing status STARTED
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class,isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
private List<Integer> getPatientsForBilling() {
    return new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Here is the logic which I have implemented

1. Once the task scheduler starts, it will get all eligible patients for billing (i.e. the patients who got discharged)
2. It will update the status as STARTED.
3. It will generate the bill
4. It will updated the status as COMPLETED

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless you use AspectJ or something like that, annotating a private method is next to useless: as far as I know Spring uses proxy AOP by default, which does not intercept self invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on your logic. As far as I understand you mark patient as STARTED, then do some complicated potentially long running task (bill creation), and then release the patient.

The actions should be isolated so you need a separate transaction for each of them and REQUIRES_NEW is fine in this case.

But your logic (shown in the posted code) has some leaks.

Imagine the makeBillForPatient() method call throws an exception. The trouble you have:

1. Patient kind of stuck in the STARTED state. You need to process somehow patients who keep STARTED status to reset them.
2. All the rest patients are not processed because you left the loop when the exception happens.

The code like this

```
    patientIds = getPatientsForBilling();
    if(null != patientIds) {
        for(Integer patient : patientIds) {
            try {
                updatePatientDetails(patient, "STARTED", jdbcTemplate);
                try {
                    makeBillForPatient(patient, jdbcTemplate);
                    updatePatientDetails(patient, "COMPLETED", jdbcTemplate);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //print something in the log here and reset patient status
                    updatePatientDetails(patient, "INITIAL", jdbcTemplate);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //print something in the log here
            }
        }
    }
```

Also don't leave empty catch blocks. In case of problem it's really hard to find the souurce. At least print something in the log.

Comment: Yes StanislavL, I'm actually handling the catch block and updating the status as well as TERMINATED and adding the reason to the patient. This is the only small snippet. Do you see any other leaks? Like for Isolation level or Propagation level?

Comment: Serializable level could be too strict as well. Why do you decide to use it? I think read committed is enough

Comment: Serializable, because its a task scheduler and the application is deployed in multiple nodes.

Comment: You can use `select for update` for single row (patient). Instead of retrieving list of patients select next patient for billing (for update) to lock one table row only, mark the patient as STARTED etc. In opposite case no benefit from multiple nodes. Patients will be queued on DB level (serializable in fact locks whole table)

Comment: The reason why I've retrieved list of patients is, it task scheduler should not hit the DB everytime for a single patient. In the time interval, it will retrieve all eligible patients and update each patient at a time. Because when the second job runs after 15 min, that job should not pick the initial patients

Comment: It sounds strange. You are trying to avoid read DB hit but one line after your call write by setting STARTED. The SELECT FOR UPDATE + UPDATE is almost the same as just UPDATE.